# Jupyter notebook %run argument not evaluated

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a python program from within a Jupyter notebook and passing it a variable like this:

```
docs = ['file1', 'file2']
for doc in docs:
    %run 'prog.py' doc
```

The problem is that "doc" is not evaluated and is taken literally, which, in my case, leads to: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'doc'

Adding -i to %run does not change the result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter Notebook expands variables with $name, bash-style.

Putting a '$' in front of the variable name works:

```
docs = ['file1', 'file2', 'file 3', 'file\ 3']
for doc in docs:
    %run 'prog.py' $doc    # <- $doc instead of doc
```

Note that you will have to replace spaces in filenames by '\ ' in order for  prog.py to be able to open the files. In the example above, you should get an error for 'file 3' but 'file\ 3' should be ok.

From [the ipython doc](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#line-magics):
*all expressions prefixed with ‘$’ get expanded. For details of the semantic rules, see PEP-215: http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0215.html. This is the library used by IPython for variable expansion. If you want to access a true shell variable, an extra $ is necessary to prevent its expansion by IPython*